# How to load Zend view

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I load a header and a footer file in Zend in a view?

1. Where should I save them?
2. Will I embed them with $this->render() in the view file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [Zend_Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.introduction.html) to include 'header' and 'footer' info.  A layout specifies your entire page layout, included in this is the content from your view script.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Zend_Layout Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html) guide.

Note: start at the end of the article to get a quick overview ([link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html#zend.layout.quickstart.example)).